# UWP exception “Could not load file or assembly Windows.Data......"

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a application UWP that I downloaded for to check how managed UWP with SQLServer from here: https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/SQLServer

When I try to Build the application I got so many errors about the Windows resource is not found,,, I have the last version of VS2017 and also W10 Pro SO....

I tried to add references and reinstall nugets, change the debug type, change the Frameworks... and I don't get works....

Can you tell me what more to do?? Maybe you can download the Project and see the same error than me...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This reference is used to call UWP APIs in "SqlBridge" windows console project.

To call UWP APIs from a classic .NET Framework application, you could install [UWPDesktop NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UwpDesktop/10.0.14393.3)

For more info, please see [Calling Windows 10 APIs From a Desktop Application](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#idL5P4edeogzEylP.97).

Comment: @ter2016 Please check if you have install the "UwpDesktop" for the "SqlBridge" project successfully. You could open the "packages.config" file to see all installed packages. And, have you install the 14393 SDK?